# File opening in Google Cloud with append

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Generally I opened a file and write contents as

```
file_put_contents('data_file.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

And I opened the same file is opened in google cloud local server as

```
file_put_contents("gs://${default_bucket}/data_file.txt", $data,);
```

What is the condition to append in google cloud??

Comment: There is no append.  You have to create a new file.

Answer (score 0):

As Jeff mentioned, there is no append. GCS does have composite objects which may work for you depending on your use case.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects